# Display categories count in loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a problem with my wordpress site.

This is my code:

```
<div id="content">
 <h1>Produkter</h1>
 <?php if (have_posts()): ?>
 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

  <div class="productcategory">
   <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php the_field('produktbild'); ?>" /></a>
   <?php the_category(); ?>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php else : ?>
   <h2 align="center">Not Found</h2>
    <p align="center">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<!-- END #content -->
```

Where you can see `<?php the_category();?>` I want to display the category name and how many posts there is in that category. Like this "Category (6)". I saw that it could be done in the categories widget so I looked it up in the widget code but I didn't get any smarter.

So the question is basically, How can I display the category name and the count after the name? Just as normal text.

I don't want to show "uncategorized" in the loop either.

Thank's!

Comment: Checkout [`get_the_category($post_id);`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) documentation.  It will return an array of `$category` objects that you can access properties like `$category->count`.

Comment: Thank you. I've read that documentation already but I don't understand how I should put it in my loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do something like the following:

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category();
$separator = ' ';
$output = '';
if($categories){
    foreach($categories as $category) {

        $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.' ('.$category->count.')'.$separator;
    }
echo trim($output, $separator);
}
?>
```

in place of:

```
<?php the_category(); ?>
```

I would recommend creating a function out of the above code and using that instead.

As for removing "uncategorized", I would suggest renaming it to something else.

Comment: Thank you! That kind of did the job.

However, I get three of the same category for some reason. why is that?

Comment: Are you sure it is not because you have 3 posts that are displaying in the loop?

Comment: I fixed the problem. I don't really know how. But it looks great now! thanks